# Is it accepted usage to "register to" a system

Tags: word-usage

The following sentence looks ungrammatical to me, but I am not sure if the usage is acceptable or not:

> You have successfully registered to the system

I am thinking it might be preferable to put in the word 'been', as follows:

> You have been successfully registered to the system

Comment: Registered with, or been registered by

Comment: @JonLarby What? These are generics sentence examples. 'with' and 'by' are not suitable.  These two sentences are  both fine if you replace 'to' with 'into'. "You have successfully registered **into** the system." "You have been successfully registered **into**  the system"

Comment: This is why I only put it as a comment - "register to sounds" completely wrong to me (Br. Eng.), "register with" sounds correct. [Apparently "register in" is most common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=registered+to%2Cregistered+with%2Cregistered+in%2Cregistered+on%2Cregistered+by%2Cregistered+into&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cregistered%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cregistered%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cregistered%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cregistered%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cregistered%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cregistered%20into%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @NormanEdward "For security purposes, I've had my fingerprints registered **with** the police." That sounds just fine to me. Which means that this is at least as much an idiomatic decision as one based on grammar. (For what it's worth, "registered **into** the system" sounds completely wrong to *me*. But I suspect all of these are arguably grammatical even if not individually idiomatic.)

Comment: @Jason Bassford *...with the police.*  'Police' signifies an agency, where 'system' is a network connection. *...with the system, in the system.', ...into the system, ...by the system,* and even *...at the system* are all grammatical, though you may find them uncomfortable. And, oddly, *...to the network* works perfectly.

Comment: It matters not at all. What you did was done exclusively within a "system" which could mean almost anything. What the Question asks is relevant only within the system and has no meaning at all in the real world… which said, why not make up your own mind, or follow the style of what institution pays you?